# RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 101, got 106

Tags: pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to use pytorch forecasting to make predictions using DeepAR.

I am getting the following error in the 2nd iteration of my training loop. I do not make any changes to the datasets after the training loop starts so I do not understand this error.

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-d2a72cad41f9> in <module>
    120       deepar,
    121       train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
--> 122       val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
    123   )
    124 

23 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in check_input(self, input, batch_sizes)
    205             raise RuntimeError(
    206                 'input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected {}, got {}'.format(
--> 207                     self.input_size, input.size(-1)))
    208 
    209     def get_expected_hidden_size(self, input: Tensor, batch_sizes: Optional[Tensor]) -> Tuple[int, int, int]:

RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 101, got 106
```

My full code is as below

```
#from ctypes import FormatError
import numpy as np

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import os,sys

# sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('C:\Work\WORK_PACKAGE\Demand_forecasting\github\DeepAR-pytorch\My_model\\2_freq_nbinom_LSTM')))

# sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('C:\Work\WORK_PACKAGE\Demand_forecasting\github\DeepAR-pytorch\My_model\\2_freq_nbinom_LSTM\\1_cluster_demand_prediction\data\weather_data')))
# sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('C:\Work\WORK_PACKAGE\Demand_forecasting\github\DeepAR-pytorch\My_model\2_freq_nbinom_LSTM\1_cluster_demand_prediction\data\demand_data')))

import torch
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)

from pytorch_forecasting.data.encoders import TorchNormalizer
from pytorch_forecasting.metrics import SMAPE, RMSE
from torchmetrics import R2Score, SymmetricMeanAbsolutePercentageError, MeanSquaredError

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pytorch_forecasting.data import TimeSeriesDataSet
from pytorch_forecasting.data import NaNLabelEncoder
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping, LearningRateMonitor
import pytorch_lightning as pl
import torch
from pytorch_forecasting.data.encoders import TorchNormalizer
import os,sys
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf,pacf
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import operator
import statsmodels.api as sm
from itertools import combinations
import pickle
from pytorch_forecasting import Baseline
import random
from pytorch_forecasting import DeepAR,NegativeBinomialDistributionLoss
from itertools import product
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error

"""
Set Random seed
"""

random.seed(0)
torch.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
## additional seeding to ensure reproduciblility.
pl.seed_everything(0)

import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/My_model/pytorch-forecasting-master/1_cluster_demand_prediction')

encoder_len = 24
pred_len = 1 # 1, 6, 12 
#cov_lag_len= pred_len # do this when creating the dataset. import that code here.

os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/My_model/pytorch-forecasting-master/1_cluster_demand_prediction')

tampines_all_clstr_train_dem_data = pd.read_csv('tampines_all_clstr_train_dem_data.csv')
tampines_all_clstr_val_dem_data = pd.read_csv('tampines_all_clstr_val_dem_data.csv')
tampines_all_clstr_test_dem_data = pd.read_csv('tampines_all_clstr_test_dem_data.csv')

tampines_all_clstr_train_dem_data = tampines_all_clstr_train_dem_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1)
tampines_all_clstr_val_dem_data = tampines_all_clstr_val_dem_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1)
tampines_all_clstr_test_dem_data = tampines_all_clstr_test_dem_data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1)

train_data = pd.DataFrame()
val_data = pd.DataFrame()
test_data = pd.DataFrame()

cov_lag_len = 0

for c in tampines_all_clstr_train_dem_data.columns:
    
    if c == 'target':  
        target_train = tampines_all_clstr_train_dem_data[c].iloc[:]
        train_data[c] = target_train.reset_index(drop=True)
        target_val = tampines_all_clstr_val_dem_data[c].iloc[:]
        val_data[c] = target_val.reset_index(drop=True)
        target_test = tampines_all_clstr_test_dem_data[c].iloc[:]
        test_data[c] = target_test.reset_index(drop=True)

    else:
        other_col_train = tampines_all_clstr_train_dem_data[c].iloc[:]
        train_data[c] = other_col_train.reset_index(drop=True)
        other_col_val = tampines_all_clstr_val_dem_data[c].iloc[:]
        val_data[c] = other_col_val.reset_index(drop=True)
        other_col_test = tampines_all_clstr_test_dem_data[c].iloc[:]
        test_data[c] = other_col_test.reset_index(drop=True)



"""
Import pre-processed Data
"""
#################### add date information ts ####################
#2021 oct 17 20:00:00
day=17
hour=(20+cov_lag_len)
if (20+cov_lag_len)>23:
  day = 18
  hour = hour%24

train_data["date"] = pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=10, day=day, hour=hour ) + pd.to_timedelta(train_data.time_idx, "H")
train_data['_hour_of_day'] = train_data["date"].dt.hour.astype(str)
train_data['_day_of_week'] = train_data["date"].dt.dayofweek.astype(str)
train_data['_day_of_month'] = train_data["date"].dt.day.astype(str)
train_data['_day_of_year'] = train_data["date"].dt.dayofyear.astype(str)
train_data['_week_of_year'] = train_data["date"].dt.weekofyear.astype(str)
train_data['_month_of_year'] = train_data["date"].dt.month.astype(str)
train_data['_year'] = train_data["date"].dt.year.astype(str)
#################### add date information ts ####################


#################### add date information ts ####################
# val starts at 3/12/2021 09:00
day=3
hour=(9+cov_lag_len)
if (9+cov_lag_len)>23:
  day = 4
  hour = hour%24

val_data["date"] = pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=12, day=day, hour=hour ) + pd.to_timedelta(val_data.time_idx, "H")
val_data['_hour_of_day'] = val_data["date"].dt.hour.astype(str)
val_data['_day_of_week'] = val_data["date"].dt.dayofweek.astype(str)
val_data['_day_of_month'] = val_data["date"].dt.day.astype(str)
val_data['_day_of_year'] = val_data["date"].dt.dayofyear.astype(str)
val_data['_week_of_year'] = val_data["date"].dt.weekofyear.astype(str)
val_data['_month_of_year'] = val_data["date"].dt.month.astype(str)
val_data['_year'] = val_data["date"].dt.year.astype(str)
#################### add date information ts ####################


#################### add date information ts ####################
# test starts at 16/12/2021 16:00
day=16
hour=(16+cov_lag_len)
if (16+cov_lag_len)>23:
  day = 17
  hour = hour%24

test_data["date"] = pd.Timestamp(year=2021, month=12, day=day, hour=hour ) + pd.to_timedelta(test_data.time_idx, "H")
test_data['_hour_of_day'] = test_data["date"].dt.hour.astype(str)
test_data['_day_of_week'] = test_data["date"].dt.dayofweek.astype(str)
test_data['_day_of_month'] = test_data["date"].dt.day.astype(str)
test_data['_day_of_year'] = test_data["date"].dt.dayofyear.astype(str)
test_data['_week_of_year'] = test_data["date"].dt.weekofyear.astype(str)
test_data['_month_of_year'] = test_data["date"].dt.month.astype(str)
test_data['_year'] = test_data["date"].dt.year.astype(str)
#################### add date information ts ####################

Target = 'target'


"""
set inputs here
(hyperparameters grid search)

"""
######### Network Architecture ###################


###### Create hyperparameters grid ###### 

hparams_grid = {"LSTM_neuron_size":[168,336,672],
                "num_layers":[3],
                "batch_size":[8,4],
                "learning_rate":[0.0001],
                "max_encoder_length":[encoder_len],
                "max_prediction_length":[pred_len],
                "dropout":[0.2],
                #"cov_pair":cov_pairs_list,# [cov_pairs_list[7]],
                "Num_epochs":[1]}
                #"Num_epochs":[16,18,20,22,24,26,28]}
###### Create hyperparameters grid ###### 

p = 10 # patience no. of epochs

Loss=NegativeBinomialDistributionLoss()

######### Network Architecture ###################
```

TRAINING ROUTINE IS BELOW.

```
######### Training Routine ###################
fdv_steps = 10 # fast_dev_run
######### Training Routine ###################


############## Inputs for 2) Persistance model ( seasonal naive forecast ) #######################
season_len = 168 # length of season
num_past_seas = 2 # number of past seasons to use in averaging
#seas_pred_strt_idx = 2035 # seasonal naive forecast start index, in hours use the df dataframe
############## Inputs for 2) Persistance model ( seasonal naive forecast ) #######################


param_comb_cnt=0
for neu,lay,bat,lr,enc_len,pred_len,drop,num_ep in product(*[x for x in hparams_grid.values()]):
    #print(param_comb_cnt,neu,lay,bat,lr,enc_len,pred_len,drop,num_ep,df_cov_col1,df_cov_col2)
    param_comb_cnt+=1
param_comb_cnt

"""
Full Training Routine 
with hyperparmeter grid search

Load data into TimeSeriesDataSet object

for fast development run
uncomment fast_dev_run = fdv_steps

"""

#early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=1e-4, patience=p, verbose=False, mode="min")
lr_logger = LearningRateMonitor()

RMSE_list = [] # FIND minimum RMSE case
hyperparams_list = [] # FIND minimum RMSE case

# best_val_comb_idx=[17,21,51,52,53,54,61,62,63,82,83,84,109,110,111,143,144,145,195,218,219,220,232,233,234,236,237,238,280,338,339,340,344,345,346,386]
# best_val_train_epochs = [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]

# best_val_comb_idx=[234]
# best_val_train_epochs = [50]
num_cols_list = []

param_comb_cnt=-1
for neu,lay,bat,lr,enc_len,pred_len,drop,num_ep in product(*[x for x in hparams_grid.values()]):
    
  param_comb_cnt+=1
  if param_comb_cnt <0 or param_comb_cnt > 50:
    continue

  # df_cov_col1 = cov_pair[0]
  # df_cov_col2 = cov_pair[1]

    ######### Load DATA #############


  cat_dict = {"_hour_of_day": NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True).fit(train_data._hour_of_day), \
  "_day_of_week": NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True).fit(train_data._day_of_week), "_day_of_month" : NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True).fit(train_data._day_of_month), "_day_of_year" : NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True).fit(train_data._day_of_year), \
      "_week_of_year": NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True).fit(train_data._week_of_year), "_month_of_year": NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True).fit(train_data._month_of_year) ,"_year": NaNLabelEncoder(add_nan=True).fit(train_data._year) }
  cat_list = ["_hour_of_day","_day_of_week","_day_of_month","_day_of_year","_week_of_year","_month_of_year","_year"]  

  num_cols_list.append('dem_lag_168') 
  num_cols_list.append('dem_lag_336')
  num_cols_list.append('inflow')
  num_cols_list.append('inf_lag_168')  
  num_cols_list.append('inf_lag_336')
  #cat_list.append('wea_desc_clstr_52')

  train_dataset = TimeSeriesDataSet(
      train_data,
      time_idx="time_idx",
      target=Target,
      categorical_encoders=cat_dict,
      group_ids=["group"],
      min_encoder_length=enc_len,
      max_encoder_length=enc_len,
      min_prediction_length=pred_len,
      max_prediction_length=pred_len,
      time_varying_unknown_reals=[Target],
      time_varying_known_reals=num_cols_list,
      time_varying_known_categoricals=cat_list,
      add_relative_time_idx=False,
      randomize_length=False,
      scalers={},
      target_normalizer=TorchNormalizer(method="identity",center=False,transformation=None )

  )

  val_dataset = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(train_dataset,val_data, stop_randomization=True, predict=False)
  test_dataset = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(train_dataset,test_data, stop_randomization=True)

  train_dataloader = train_dataset.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=bat)
  val_dataloader = val_dataset.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=bat)
  test_dataloader = test_dataset.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=bat)
  ######### Load DATA #############


  """
  Machine Learning predictions START
  1) DeepAR

  """
  trainer = pl.Trainer(
      max_epochs=num_ep,
      gpus=-1, #-1
      auto_lr_find=False,
      gradient_clip_val=0.1,
      limit_train_batches=1.0,
      limit_val_batches=1.0,
      #fast_dev_run=fdv_steps,
      logger=True,
      #log_every_n_steps=10,
      # profiler=True,
      callbacks=[lr_logger]#, early_stop_callback],
      #enable_checkpointing=True,
      #default_root_dir="C:\Work\WORK_PACKAGE\Demand_forecasting\github\DeepAR-pytorch\My_model\2_freq_nbinom_LSTM\1_cluster_demand_prediction\logs"
  )


  #print(f"training routing:\n \n {trainer}")
  deepar = DeepAR.from_dataset(
      train_dataset,
      learning_rate=lr,
      hidden_size=neu,
      rnn_layers=lay,
      dropout=drop,
      loss=Loss,
      log_interval=20,
      log_val_interval=6,
      log_gradient_flow=False,
      # reduce_on_plateau_patience=3,
  )

    
  #print(f"Number of parameters in network: {deepar.size()/1e3:.1f}k")
  # print(f"Model :\n \n {deepar}")
  torch.set_num_threads(10)
  trainer.fit(
      deepar,
      train_dataloaders=train_dataloader,
      val_dataloaders=val_dataloader,
  )

  ########## Prediction #####################

  test_output = deepar.predict(data=test_dataloader,mode='prediction',return_index=True,num_workers=8,show_progress_bar=True)

  len1 = test_output[1]['time_idx'].shape[0]

  actual1_full = np.array([])
  pred_full = np.array([])  
  RMSE_list = np.array([])

  old_pred_idx = test_output[1]['time_idx'][0]

  for i in range(len1):
      pred_idx = test_output[1]['time_idx'][i]
      if pred_idx - old_pred_idx > 1: # moved into new group
          plt.figure(figsize=(25,5))
          plt.plot(actual1_full.flatten(),'^-')
          plt.plot(pred_full.flatten(),'*-')
          plt.show()
          RMSE = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual1_full.flatten(),pred_full.flatten() ))
          print('Average RMSE : ', RMSE)
          actual1_full = np.array([])
          pred_full = np.array([])

      actual = test_data[Target].iloc[pred_idx:pred_idx+pred_len].values
      actual1_full = np.append(actual1_full, actual)

      pred = np.array(np.rint(test_output[0][i])).astype(int)
      pred_full = np.append(pred_full, pred)
      old_pred_idx = pred_idx
      i=i+pred_len

  plt.figure(figsize=(25,5))
  plt.plot(actual1_full.flatten(),'^-')
  plt.plot(pred_full.flatten(),'*-')
  plt.show()
  RMSE = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual1_full.flatten(),pred_full.flatten() ))
  print('Average RMSE : ', RMSE)

  print('\n Hyperparameter: param_comb_cnt,neu,lay,bat,lr,enc_len,pred_len,drop,num_ep,inflow\n')
  print(param_comb_cnt,neu,lay,bat,lr,enc_len,pred_len,drop,num_ep,' \n')
  ########## Prediction #####################
    
  # TO find minimum RMSE
  hyperparams_list.append((neu,lay,bat,lr,enc_len,pred_len,drop,num_ep))
  # RMSE_list.append(RMSE)

  

  """
  Machine Learning predictions END
  """

######## Identify least RMSE case #############
# min_RMSE_idx = RMSE_list.index(min(RMSE_list))
# hyperparams_list[min_RMSE_idx]

######## Identify least RMSE case #############
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was here:

```
  num_cols_list.append('dem_lag_168') 
  num_cols_list.append('dem_lag_336')
  num_cols_list.append('inflow')
  num_cols_list.append('inf_lag_168')  
  num_cols_list.append('inf_lag_336')
```

I should perform this append outside the loop only once as it is a one-time operation and should not be in every hyperparameter combination.

That was why the got was more by 5 (i.e. expected 101, got 106)